# Wadge Hierarchy on $\Delta^{0}_{2}$ sets

Tags: descriptive-set-theory, the-baire-space

i'm studying the Wadge hierarchy on Baire space and Cantor space. I'm asking whether or not the $\Delta^0_2$ sets form a unique degree in these spaces and why the $\Sigma^0_2$-true (i.e. not polish) subsets of $2^\omega$ form a unique degree. Moreover, which results for $\omega^\omega$ can i say also for $2^\omega$?

I'll thanks anyone let me know more about the relation between wadge hierarchy and on these spaces and their boldface pointclasses.

Comment: Thank you! See you around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer about the boldface versions.

The ambiguous class $\boldsymbol\Delta_2^0$ comprises $\omega_1$ levels of the Wadge hierarchy (see Kecrhis' book on descriptive set theory, Exercise 21.16, and the many references therein).

Sets in $\boldsymbol\Sigma_\alpha^0 \setminus \boldsymbol\Pi_\alpha^0$ are complete, and from this it follows that they are all inter-reducible, and hence in a unique degree.

Finally, all the results hold uniformly of all zero dimensional Polish spaces, in particular $A^\omega$ for any countable $A$.

You might also be interested in the [comment by A. Caicedo](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3642050/borel-hierarchy-within-wadge-hierarchy#comment7484275_3642050) to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3642050/212120).

Comment: Thanks you for the advice about Kechris' book, it's always a mine of useful and hidden results. Also Alessandro Andretta is a master in subject, i'll contact him for other questions.

Comment: Thank you very much. If the answer was of some use to you, please consider upvoting (and accepting if you consider the issue closed).